# Using Git, should a hotfix branch merge with development branch or should it be the other way around?

Tags: git, git-branch

I wonder why in the Pro Git book (Apress 2009), the example in Chapter 3 is:

1. Everything committed on the `master` branch now, already pushed to production
2. Created an `iss53` branch for development of a feature, added some temporary changes, and committed.
3. A hot fix is required, so switch to `master` branch and create a `hotfix` branch
4. Fix the bug (such as a typo for the tech support email address), and committed, and push to production
5. Switch to `master` branch and merge with `hotfix` branch
6. (optionally) delete the `hotfix` branch

Right at this point, I wonder why the book would go to the `master` branch and do a merge with the `iss53` branch.  Won't this actually make the master branch in an intermediate state?  What if another hot fix is required, then master is not good for doing a hot fix, and we have to manually choose the commit that is before the merge.  Shouldn't the merge be, going to the `iss53` branch and merge with the `hotfix` branch, so that what was wrong will now be incorporated into a future release as well?

**Update:** actually, the book had an assumption that the `iss53` work is complete, and do the last merge.  But what if the work on `iss53` is not done yet, and we want to merge in the hot fix?

Comment: In your example iss53 is not merged with master

Comment: I think OP is talking about the scenario here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 0):

@動靜能量,

In that case, you have three choice:

1. `cherry-pick` the `hotfix` commits to `iss53`
2. Merge `master` to `iss53`
3. Rebase `iss53` onto `master`

Personally, I prefer #3. Because it give cleaner history.

However, if you have too many developer (like linux do), #2 may be easier. This should be rare. In that case, make sure you merge `master` on a stable point (e.g. a stable point release, not some random testing state), so the history won't go too complex.

LWN have [an article](http://lwn.net/Articles/328436/) discuss this in detail.

Comment: For (2), does that mean switch to `iss53` and merge with `master`, or switch to `master` and merge with `iss53`?

Comment: for (2), switch to `iss53` and type `git merge master`.

Answer (score 0):

If work on `iss53` is not complete but you want the hotfix, you can merge `master` into `iss53`, or (better) rebase `iss53` on top of `master`.

Merge:

```
git checkout iss53
git merge --no-ff master # --no-ff keeps the master tip where it is
```

Rebase (you'll get to this later in the chapter):

```
git checkout iss53
git rebase master
```